# ¿Que está mal de este bubbleSort?

Tags: c++

Es muy raro el error que estoy teniendo...Si hago un `bubbleSort`, es decir, solo del alumnos1 y lo imprimo anda perfecto. Ahora si le agrego al main, que haga el `bubbleSort` con alumnos2 y alumnos1, y luego los imprima(de forma separada como se ve en el código) crashea.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Alumno {
    int nroLegajo;
    int idMateria;
};

void bubbleSort(Alumno alumnos[],int n) {
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {//i hace 8 veces. del 0 al 7
        for (int j=0;j<n-i;j++) {//j hace 8-i. del 0 al 7-i
            if (
                (alumnos[j].nroLegajo > alumnos[j+1].nroLegajo)//Ordena por nroLegajo
                ||
                ((alumnos[j].nroLegajo == alumnos[j+1].nroLegajo) && (alumnos[j].idMateria > alumnos[j+1].idMateria))
                )//Si el nroLegajo son iguales, ordena por idMateria
            {
                Alumno aux = alumnos[j];
                alumnos[j] = alumnos[j+1];
                alumnos[j+1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Alumno alumnos1[6] = {
        {5,4},
        {2,6},
        {7,11},
        {5,8},
        {9,2},
        {9,1}
    };

    Alumno alumnos2[6] = {
        {2,6},
        {3,8},
        {1,12},
        {2,3},
        {6,4},
        {8,4}
    };

    bubbleSort(alumnos1, 6);

    bubbleSort(alumnos2, 6);

    for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
        cout << alumnos1[i].nroLegajo << " " << alumnos1[i].idMateria << endl;
    }

    cout << " " << endl;

    for (int e=0;e<6;e++) {
        cout << alumnos2[e].nroLegajo << " " << alumnos2[e].idMateria << endl;
    }  
}
```

Esto es el error que lanza, además pueden ver en la consola que imprime un número raro(seguramente me equivoque en los límites del array pero no veo donde).

[image: Imagen del error]

Comment: Estuve 10m intentando que se ponga en formato de código pero no pude. Si alguien puede editarlo y hacerlo se lo agradecería mucho y de paso explicarme como lo hago

Comment: Hola, ya he editado tu código. Puedes seleccionar tu código completo y utilizar las teclas `Cntrl + K` para darle formato. Un saludo :)

Comment: Mil gracias! Pensé que era con " ` "

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar a la pregunta también el error que te está dando actualmente?

Comment: Agregó una imagen, mas fácil.

Answer (score 1):

En el primer for inicias desde cero cuando tendrias que hacerlo desde 1.

```
void bubbleSort(Alumno alumnos[],int n) {
    for (int i=1;i<n;i++) {//i hace 8 veces. del 0 al 7
        for (int j=0;j<n-i;j++) {//j hace 8-i. del 0 al 7-i
            //Ordena por nroLegajo
            if ((alumnos[j].nroLegajo > alumnos[j+1].nroLegajo)||
                ((alumnos[j].nroLegajo == alumnos[j+1].nroLegajo) && (alumnos[j].idMateria > alumnos[j+1].idMateria)))
                    //Si el nroLegajo son iguales, ordena por idMateria
            {
                Alumno aux = alumnos[j];
                alumnos[j] = alumnos[j+1];
                alumnos[j+1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah claro, lo hace n-1 veces porque la última etapa(i=7) se ordenan dos indexes juntos o me equivoco?

Answer (score 0):

Una solución más natural: El segundo bucle debe iterar en el rango (`0<=j<i`):

```
void bubbleSort(Alumno alumnos[],int n) {
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {//i hace 8 veces. del 0 al 7
        for (int j=0;j<i;j++) {//j hace 8-i. del 0 al 7-i
        //           ^^^
            if (
                (alumnos[j].nroLegajo > alumnos[j+1].nroLegajo)//Ordena por nroLegajo
                ||
                ((alumnos[j].nroLegajo == alumnos[j+1].nroLegajo) && (alumnos[j].idMateria > alumnos[j+1].idMateria))
                )//Si el nroLegajo son iguales, ordena por idMateria
            {
                Alumno aux = alumnos[j];
                alumnos[j] = alumnos[j+1];
                alumnos[j+1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

De esta forma los dos bucles tienen un inicio natural (en cero)